# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to retrieve JSON data on my website. The problem is when I run the code I get an error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

My JSON:

```
{
    "metadata": {
        "language": "en-US",
        "transaction_id": "1464687780497:-1422910090",
        "version": "1",
        "latitude": 33.26,
        "longitude": 44.23,
        "units": "m",
        "expire_time_gmt": 1464688380,
        "status_code": 200
    }
}
```

My jQuery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function (weather) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://meteoiraq.com/warring.json",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function (data) {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.metadata.length; i++) {
                html += '<h1 class="text-center">التحذيرات الجوية</h3>';
                html += '<h2>' + data.metadata.language + '</h2>';
                html += '</div>';
                $("#deatils").append(html).hide().fadeIn("slow");
                //next ho
            }
        }
    }); //add this code. Need to close the 'jQuery(document)'
}); // a
```

Comment: Why is your dataType `jsonp`?

Comment: Also, `length` property applies to array and `data.metadata` is not an array

Comment: Also, you can remove the `weather` property from your DOMReady handler function definition.

Answer (score 0):

I think below code will work

try Using getJSON method of ajax and also try changing "#deatils" to "#details" as i guess you might be mis-spelling the exact name

Hope this helps.